# The "does not implement interface member" error when using inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have these 2 interfaces:

```
public interface IFilterHelper<T>
{
    void Filter(ISearchModel<T> model, ref IQueryable<T> dbModel);
}

public interface ISearchModel<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetDBModel(DbContext db);
}
```

And these 2 implementations

```
public class UserSearchModel : ISearchModel<ApplicationUser>
{        
    public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> GetDBModel(DbContext db)
    {
        return db.Users.Where(u => true); //something like this
    }
}

public class UserFilterHelper : IFilterHelper<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Filter(UserSearchModel model, ref IQueryable<ApplicationUser> dbModel)
    {
    }
}
```

However I get the error `'UserFilterHelper' does not implement interface member 'IFilterHelper<ApplicationUser>.Filter(ISearchModel<ApplicationUser>, ref IQueryable<ApplicationUser>)'`

But when I change `UserSearchModel` with `ISearchModel<ApplicationUser>`, it compiles successfully. I know I can cast it and get it to work but why does it give me that error. As you can see the `UserSearchModel` class implements the interface `ISearchModel<ApplicationUser>`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface explicitly requires `ISearchModel<ApplicationUser>` and even though `UserSearchModel` implements `ISearchModel<ApplicationUser>` it isn't the only one that could. I could create a class `SuperUserSearchModel` that also would implement the same interface.

So trying to write `public void Filter(UserSearchModel model, ref IQueryable<ApplicationUser> dbModel)` means you are restricting the implementation of the interface.

To make it work you would have to design your interface like this:

```
public interface IFilterHelper<T, R> where R : ISearchModel<T>
{
    void Filter(R model, ref IQueryable<T> dbModel);
}

public class UserFilterHelper : IFilterHelper<ApplicationUser, UserSearchModel>
{
    public void Filter(UserSearchModel model, ref IQueryable<ApplicationUser> dbModel)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now that I read your answer I see where I was wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your UserFilterHelper has the wrong type of parameter in the filter method:

```
    public class UserFilterHelper : IFilterHelper<ApplicationUser> {

public void Filter(ISearchModel<ApplicationUser> /* Not UserSearchModel */ model, ref IQueryable<ApplicationUser> dbModel)
{
}
```

}

You will still pass the 'UserSearchModel' in as the parameter. It is only the method signature that requires it to be ISearchModel

Comment: I would say @Enigmativity has the better approach. But both ways will work.

Comment: Because the Interface signature requires ISearchModel<T> regardless of what or whom implements it. The signature has to be ISearchModel<T>. To get around that issue you will have to do what Enigmativity proposed